# How can I make a special URL like "http://appname/

Tags: networking, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I know some applications run on companies' internal networks with URLS like "https:/statsd/", so I was wondering how to go about doing this.  I was thinking maybe I would use a reverse proxy like Nginx to proxy all urls that match a particular regex to the correct server, but I don't really know where I would even put that reverse proxy to begin with.

Can someone point me to some resources where I can learn more about this stuff?  Thanks so much!!

Comment: I am not fully sure what you are saying, but the companies can do this by making a reference to that servers host name. `https://servername/` and by running some sort of web server on said server it can redirect you to the app.

Comment: Yes, you need a kind of redirection from `http://appname/` to `http://appserver/appname`.

Comment: Basically you would need whatever special app name you would like to have be the name of your server on the domain, with a HTTP or (s) server that can handle sending requests to different servers or applications

Comment: This kind of question is probably better suited to https://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to run your own DNS server on the intranet with rules for these names. For implementing the server, you may wish to look into Zonefiles with [BIND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIND).

How to configure machines on your network to use this DNS server is a matter of how network settings for machines on the intranet are configured. If using [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol), this is a matter of configuring the intranet's DHCP server to offer that as the DNS server. If using some other kind of out-of-band configuration (such as hardcoded settings when imaging machines), you would need to add a rule in whatever mechanism you're using to specify the network settings to configure the network interface to use your internal DNS server.

As for handling HTTP requests for those names, that's a job for a reverse proxy like [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html), as you said. In the DNS server's rules, you would want to point any names meant to be handled by the reverse proxy server *to* the reverse proxy server, obviously.

(As a simpler-to-instantiate-but-harder-to-manage alternative to setting up a DNS server, you could come up with a way to add addresses for all the names you want to each machine's [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))).